# Intervals of Existence of the solution to $x^2 y' = (1 - x^2)(1 + y^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm curious about the intervals of existence of the DE in question. It is solvable via separation of variables, upon which one receives
$$
y = \tan\left(-\frac1x - x + C\right)
$$
for arbitrary constant $C$. The problem is that the intervals of existence of this equation are quite ugly to express neatly. Namely, they are the simply-connected components of the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ -\frac1x-x+C\neq \pi(n+1/2)\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. One can find these intervals explicitly quite simply using the quadratic formula, but I dislike this solution because

1. It leads to really ugly intervals (though I'm not sure there's any nicer way of getting the intervals of existence).
2. It doesn't give much intuition for how the interval of existence is related to the initial DE. Why can't $x\in\mathbb{R}$? In the original DE, why should we expect the solution not to exist at these rather odd points?